# Database for massive update and read on a single entity

Tags: mongodb, machine-learning, distributed-computing, database, nosql

I'm currently implementing a distributed online machine learning framework. Basically this system process datastream of samples. The model (e.g. perceptron layer(s)) will be updated with each sample.

So, I'm looking for a database which can support massive update and read on a single entity. I think that mongodb and it's "update-in-place" is a good choice but maybe there's a database which fits better to my needs.

Comment: mongodb may work just fine. There's only one way to know. :)

Comment: why not do the updates in-memory, and just store backup in plain file?

Comment: The model needs to be readed/updated from different machines in a cluster (it's a distributed system). In-memory updates will lead to different models on each instance in the cluster.

Answer (score 0):

I'll venture an answer ...

I will give the disclaimer that I've become a pretty big fan of Mongo, so take that into account. =)

Mongo would be a good choice for reads, but only *if* you are willing to have data be slightly inconsistent. Mongo has a thing called a replica set, which is basically a cluster.

The replica set has only *one* machine that can receive writes/updates. It handles them well, but it's something to consider. It's not a master/master replication set up.

As writes/updates come in, they are replicated to other nodes in the replica set. This is where the eventual consistency comes in.

You can consider something like Couchbase/CouchDB, which also has a cluster concept and it's master/master. You can write to any node and it will eventually be available on other nodes.

Some things to think about.

EDIT:

I'd go with Mongo. =)